# Test `.in` files in Java program

Tags: input-methods

I have a folder with some input files (text files with extention `.in`).

In same folder, I have made a Java program. I want to test the input of all the input files in this Java program.

In a GUI, I would just copy the text content in the input file and paste it in the console when I run my Java program, but I wonder if there is a really smart way to test the input files in the vim editor.

Answer (score 5):

Not really a job for Vim. Use make or a plain bash script to run your tests. You can use Vim's `:make` integration to run the whole battery from the editor. `:help makeprg` if you are not writing a Makefile.

Example `Makefile`:

```
test: *.in

%.in: FORCE
    java MyProgram $@

FORCE:
```

Then a simple `:make` (or `:make test`, if you defined other rules) will suffice. If you don't want to make another file, you could do something ugly like this:

```
:set makeprg=bash\ -c\ 'for\ i\ in\ *.in;\ do\ java\ MyProgram\ $i;\ done'
```

(remember to escape every space, and triple-escape every vertical bar.) With this, again, `:make` runs everything.

If you really are asking for a Vim answer, I guess it would be something like

```
:r!ls *.in
:g/^/execute ":!java MyProgram ".getline(".")
```

Comment: If I just want to run one input file at a time, what should I do? If I just want to run input the content of `abc.in` in my java program?

Comment: `:!java MyProgram abc.in` should be good, no?

Comment: And if you have the input file loaded up in Vim, you can just do `:!java MyProgram %`. Further, you could change the `'makeprg'` for .in files also... `:let &makeprg = 'java MyProgram %'`...

Comment: If I'm in the shell and I have the files `MyProgram.java` and `MyProgram.class`, I can edit the java file in vim with `vim MyProgram.java` and run the compiled java program with `java MyProgram`. But if I write `:!java MyProgram abc.in`, it doesn't work. I guess I'm messing up what should be written in the console and what should be written in vim.

Comment: Indeed, `:!java MyProgram abc.in` is a vim command. It is also sensitive to the current directory (check `:pwd`). There is no "one true answer" here, since all of it is very contextual, and you'd need to tweak according to your project structure and what exactly you are trying to achieve.